# Данные в базу заносятся с запятой в начале

Tags: python, sqlite3, aiogram

Мне необходимо занести в базу данных значение userid, но при определённых условиях запись будет разная:

```
cur.execute(
    f'''SELECT pasw FROM users WHERE user_id LIKE "{useridlike}"'''
)
pasw = cur.fetchone()[0]

if pasw is None:
    cur.execute(
        f'''UPDATE users SET pasw = {message.from_user.id} WHERE user_id = "{useridlike}"'''
    )  # Сохраняем ему в pasw наш userid, при условии, что до этого строка была пустой.

else:
    cur.execute(
        f'''UPDATE users SET pasw = "{pasw}, {message.from_user.id}" WHERE user_id = "{useridlike}"'''
)  # Сохраняем ему в pasw наш userid, при условии, что до этого строка была не пустой.
```

Однако, если до этого строка была пустая, то значение заносится с запятой в начале строки: 

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
if pasw is None:
```

Сделай просто

```
if pasw:
```

Оно также будет срабатывать если строка не пустая. Елсе будет срабатывать если она пустая.